# Tried to make function to get number of max rows Pygame

Tags: python, function, pygame

So the main code works like this:

```
import sys, pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from pygame.sprite import Group
import game_function as gf

def run_game():
    #initialize game and create a screen object
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))

    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion 2000")
    #Make ship
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    #make a group to store bullets in
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()
    #create the fleet of aliens
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens)

    #start the main loop for game
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)        
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
run_game()
```

Additionally I have a module called game_function.py, but the only part of game_function which is not working is these last parts def(get_number_aliens_x, create_alien and create_fleet). Which returns errors. First I thought I missed something reading the book Python Crashcourse, but I've went through the newly added code many times now with no avail. The book mentions a name 'alien_number' but I can't figure out where to place it

**Question: does anybody see what's wrong, where the 'alien_number' needs to be inserted or have a answer for why the error generates?**

What it's supposed to do: get a image from another file called Alien (150x150px .png) and try to see how many rows it can fill the game with:

```
import sys, pygame
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses"""
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ship.moving_up = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
            #lyckas inte stänga av spelet
            #elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
             #   sys.exit()

def check_keyup_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """Respond to keyreleases"""
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #lyckas inte stänga av spelet
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship)


def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to new screen."""
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    #redraw all bullets behind ship and aliens
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()
    aliens.draw(screen)
    #make the most recently drawn screen visible
    pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(bullets):
    """update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets"""
    #updates bullet position
    bullets.update()

    #get rid of bullets that have disappeared
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Fire a bullet if limit not reached yet"""
    #Create a new bullet and add it to the bullet group
    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
                    #create a new bullet and add it to the bullet group
                    new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
                    bullets.add(new_bullet)

def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
    """Determine the number of aliens that can fit in a row"""
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x

def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, aliens_number):
    """Create an alien and place it in the row"""
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    aliens.add(alien)

def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens):
    """Create a full fleet of aliens"""
    #create an alien and find ithe number of alien in a row
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)


    #create the first row of alien
    for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
        create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number)
```

--

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python\alien_invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 29, in <module>
    run_game()
  File "python\alien_invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 21, in run_game
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens)
  File "python\alien_invasion\game_function.py", line 94, in create_fleet
    create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number)
  File "python\alien_invasion\game_function.py", line 81, in create_alien
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
NameError: name 'alien_number' is not defined
```

beginning of path deleted, not any concern.

Comment: Do you have a question? What is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your param is named `aliens_number` (plural) but you're trying to use it as `alien_number` (singular).

```
def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, aliens_number):
    # ... 
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, this did the trick.